# Getting out of while loop on console

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal

I ran a command:

```
while true ; do ..... ....... ; done
```

on the Linux console/terminal, and now this while loop is continuously running.

I have two questions here:

1. How to get out of this `while` loop?
2. If my PuTTY session to Linux gets disconnected, how can I go back and find this loop and kill it?

Answer (score 3):

You can cancel the loop with: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

Your session would have ended when your putty session closed so the loop will no longer be running

- unless it was running in a [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) session or similar in which case you would have to reattach it using the method of that particular program.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes hitting control-c doesn't work: the loop body gets the control-c and the loop keeps iterating.  (Although I can't reproduce this behaviour right now with `sleep 1` as the loop condition or the body, I remember seeing it.)

control-z can stop this, and the loop won't resume after `fg` unless the loop was inside a subshell like `(while true;do : ;done)`.  (With `bash` on GNU/Linux).

Or control-z / `fg` is useful if you want the currently-running iteration of the loop to finish cleanly, but not start another iteration.

(Control-z stops a job, getting the kernel to deliver SIGTSTP exactly like how control-c delivers SIGINT, on a TTY that's not in raw mode.  The default action for this signal is to stop the job.  `fg` and `bg` are job-control commands, see the bash built-in "help" for them and the `jobs` command.)

Answer (score 1):

Given what @PeterCordes correctly points out, that Ctrl-C doesn't always work, a solution I sometimes use is to avoid making the loop infinite.  Instead, I often write:

```
while sleep 1; do ...; done
```

If that one-second delay is too much of a slowdown, such as when you want to loop as quickly as possible, then condition the `while` loop on the presence of a semaphore file:

```
touch /tmp/ENABLE-LOOP-FILE
while [ -f '/tmp/ENABLE-LOOP-FILE' ]; do ...; done
```

When you need to kill the loop, go to another terminal session and remove the file:

```
rm /tmp/ENABLE-LOOP-FILE
```